# Memory mapped files in PHP, what is the difference between php://temp and php://memory

Tags: php, memory-mapped-files

I am in need of a way to store a file in memory very briefly in PHP, the file is being built and then sent right off to another web service. I see that as of PHP 5.1 the `php://temp` and `php://memory` streams are available, but there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of difference between the two: `php://temp` supports the `stream_select()` function and `php://memory` does not. Which one should I be using in this case, or is there a better way to do memory mapped files in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight out of [the relevant manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> The php://memory wrapper stores the
>   data in the memory. php://temp behaves
>   similarly, but uses a temporary file
>   for storing the data when a certain
>   memory limit is reached (the default
>   is 2 MB).

<sub>**Source:** I went on Google and searched for `php temp memory`. This was the first result, with the answer in the extract.</sub>

`php://temp` sounds appropriate for your use case.

Comment: That's where I started, sorry I didn't see it down there in the example code section. Silly me for thinking it would be in the summary section where it lists the differences between the streams...

Comment: @Graham: This is the PHP documentation, after all. :)