# PHP write data to memory as a file

Tags: php, memory-mapped-files

Is there a way in PHP to create a file that can be read by `fopen` like a regular file, but in-fact exists in memory? For security, I'd like to not ever hit disk, but due to external factors I need to pass a filesystem path along further in code.

`tmpfile()` is close, but this seems to write the file to disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory mapped files in PHP, what is the difference between php://temp and php://memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005342/memory-mapped-files-in-php-what-is-the-difference-between-php-temp-and-php)

Comment: How do I write and read data from `php://memory` though?

Comment: `$file = fopen('php://memory', 'rw+');`

Comment: Yeah, I a using a required 3rd party function that expects a string file path, passing the memory file handle does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know in that case, it's a shame that it doesn't accept an input stream.